# What is the Sqlite analogue for table literals as in Postgresql or Sybase?

Tags: sqlite

What is the Sqlite analogue for table literals as in Postgresql or Sybase?

```
select * from (values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')) as t(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such table literals are supported since version 3.8.3, as part of the common table expression support.

To specify column names, you must use an actual common table expression:

```
WITH t(x, y) AS (
  VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Comment: LOL. And now guess which version I have to use: 3.8.2! The code in your example is exactly what I tried to use. The older version says: `Error: near "WITH": syntax error`

Comment: BTW: is there another way to iterate an update statement though a replacement list of pairs?

Comment: That would be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in SQLite (tested with 3.14). However the alias specifying the column names is not supported.

So this works:

```
select * 
from (values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')) as t;
```

I don't know how to specify the alias for the columns though.